# How to repeat a block of text?

Tags: text-processing, awk

How do I use `awk` to repeat a block of text 100 times?

ie

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Would become:

```
string1
string2
string3
string1
string2
string3
string1
string2
string3...
```

Comment: Do you need to repeat only a section of your input or the whole input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(where `input` is a file containing the text to repeat)

With GNU `awk` (and assuming the input doesn't contain NUL bytes):

```
awk -v n=100 -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{while (n--) print}' < input
```

Portably:

```
awk -v n=100 -v ORS= '
  {all = all $0 RS}
  END {while (n--) print all}' < input
```

(note that if the input didn't end with a newline character, one will be added).

You can also do things like:

```
set --
n=100; while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
  set -- "$@" input
  n=$((n - 1))
done
cat "$@"
```

That one will work regardless of what byte `input` contains. Note however, that for larger values of `n`, and if your shell doesn't have `cat` builtin you may reach the system limit on the size of the arguments to a command (here `cat`).

With `zsh` or recent versions of `bash` or `ksh93` or `yash -o braceexpand`, for a fixed text you can do things like:

```
printf '%.0sstring1\nstring2\nstring3\n' {1..100}
```

With `zsh`:

```
repeat 100 print -l string{1..3}
```

If we're being cheeky, on systems with GNU `seq` installed, we can also do:

```
seq -f 'string1
string2
string%.0g' 3.0001 0.0001 3.0100
```

Comment: seq -f .. how to work?! and why use 3.0001 to 3.0100 !?! why not use 1 to 100 ?!?!  thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is tagged `awk`, I would like to add a simple solution that does not use `awk`:

```
seq 100 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo "1 2 3"
```

If the data you with to repeat is in a file, use this instead:

```
seq 100 | xargs -n1 -I{} cat filename
```

Another solution might use the command `yes`, which simply repeats its arguments:

```
yes "1 2 3" | head -n100
```

Comment: Note that it runs one `echo`/`cat` command per iteration.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know. But I like the functional approach.

Comment: I think we can safely assume "a block of text" consists of several lines...

Comment: @don_crissti So what? You can use `"$(echo -e whatever)"` or `"$(<input)"` as an argument to `yes`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs, yes though you'd need to adapt the number passed to `head -n` based on the number of lines in the `input` (like `head -n 300` for a 3-line input). Also note that `$(<input)` strips all trailing newlines from the content of `input` (`yes` will add **one** back).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'll admit the newline stripping might be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
echo "t1 t2 t3" | awk '{l=$0; for(i=1;i++<100;) l=l" "$0} END{print l}'
```

AND with `perl`:

```
echo "t1 t2 t3" | perl -ne 'chomp;print "$_ " x 100;'
```

Comment: (note that this answer is based on [the original version of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/296711/1) that had a formatting issue that caused the blocks of text to appear on a single line)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AWK I would simply use a for-loop:

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
    echo string1
    echo string2
    echo string3
done
```

Comment: That's running 301 commands (one of which non-standard) instead of one `awk` one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `echo` is a shell builtin, so it does not have the overhead of an external command.

Answer (score 0):

On `/bin/bash`, you can parameterize your printed records, so you can print any three values among your file records, n times in a row. They do not have to be consecutive.

Say you want to print out records 2, 3 and 6 from your input file: `inputfile`

```
$ cat inputfile
A
B
C
D
E
F
$ awk -v RS='\n' '{if(NR=="2"||NR=="3"||NR=="6") a[NR]=$0} \
END{for(i=1;i++<=100;) {print a[2]"\n"a[3]"\n"a[6];}}' inputfile
```

Arguably this costs a little more because an array is invoked.

Comment: Provided as a reaction to @don_crissti's comment ...

Comment: You misread my comment though maybe it's my fault as I wasn't clear enough... Obviously, extracting a section of text and repeating it is as simple as repeating the whole input...What I meant was "repeat only a section of the input while leaving the rest of the input intact..."

Comment: @don_crissti: I now got what you meant. It was indeed not clear from OP's phrasing... Different but still feasible in more than one way.   Good homework for class.